# file not found -fobjc-link-runtime

Tags: objective-c

I have this error in objective c

-fobjc-link-runtime it say's file not found. I've been googling but failed to get what caused the error. I'm building it on a xcode4.5 environment. using ios6 as base sdk. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same issue. Turns out it was due to my having left a -force_load option in the Other Linker Flags, that turned out to be followed by -fobj-link-runtime, causing the linker to think that was a library.

Answer (score 0):

That looks an awful lot like a spurious linker flag that leaked through from some kind of ObjC testing harness.

I.e. you need to go to the build settings editor in Xcode, find whatever is setting that particular flag, and remove it.

Comment: you mean i should to to other linker flags? then delete the one that looks like -fobjc-link-runtime? but when i do that there's no -fobj-link-runtime on the list