# How to fix this error: "ld: file not found: -fobjc-link-runtime"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I am trying to build my project and I am getting the error `ld: file not found: -fobjc-link-runtime`. 
  I have never seen this before and searching for it hasn't returned much.  Does anyone know what would cause this and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your compile sources for that.  It appears either you or Xcode is confusing a compiler flag with a file name.

Comment: I think you might not link the framework that's needed as dependence.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741189/file-not-found-fobjc-link-runtime

Answer (score 0):

It might be some xcode problem. Save the code and restart xcode.
It might fix your problem